# How can you transfer an image from a web page to a Native Client application?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I was wondering how you can transfer an image from a web page to a Native Client application.

I have two main use cases:
1.) A user uploads an image from their filesystem
2.) An image is captured from the web camera and saved in a canvas element

I have looked at the documentation under imageData, but I am not sure exactly how to use this, or if that is even the right approach.

I know also that we can use the message framework to pass data, but I wasn't sure if that method was efficient in any way, for images that are least 640x480.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer image data from JS to NaCl via the PostMessage API.

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
NaClModule.postMessage(imageData.data.buffer);
```

In addition, you can actually hand the fileBlob URL to NaCl (also via postmessage), and using the pp::GetURL API, fetch the file directly. This will allow you to popup a file-chooser in JS, and have NaCl load the file, rather than having JS load it, and pass it over.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Nacl-mounts in Nacl ports. You can load image files from the server using http2mount classes. However, as of now, I don't think there is any way to access Camera from Nacl. They are yet to release camera api.